# Fermat's equation with real exponents

Tags: number-theory

Just out of curiosity : has the equation
$$
x^r+y^r=z^r,\qquad(x,y,z)\in\Bbb Z^3,\quad r\in\Bbb R,
$$
been studied? Any non trivial result for $r\in\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb N$ ?

Comment: My question was marked as a duplicate of a question that was posed 5 months *after* mine was. math.stackexchange watchdogs like time paradoxes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For information on rational exponents, see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_Last_Theorem#Rational_exponents). In particular, see [this](http://www.math.leidenuniv.nl/~hwl/PUBLICATIONS/1992d/art.pdf) paper. Clearly there are real values for which the theorem is false, by a continuity argument.

Comment: I'm not sure what is the continuity argument you are thinking of.

Comment: @AndreaMori Define for example $f(r) = 4^r+5^r-6^r$, which is continuous in $r.$ Then $f(2) >0 $ and $f(3)< 0$ so by the intermediate value theorem there is some $2<r<3$ such that $4^r+5^r = 6^r.$

Comment: ah, ok, sure. Your "the theorem is false" somehow made me think that you were taking a fixed value of $r$.