# Are there distinct integers $A,B,C \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $A^e + B^e=C^e$

Tags: analysis, number-theory

This question is a variant of the pythagorean relation except that 2 was replaced by $e=2.71828...$

Comment: See [this MSE-question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/257382/fermats-equation-with-real-exponents).